# Conversion of Facebook payload to sha1 value to check and match with x-hub-signation

Tags: facebook, security, chatbot, messenger

I am trying to implement facebook webhook security.

The below code works fine for text messages but the moment attachments are sent , the sha value doesnot match.

I tried calculating on the escaped Unicode lowercase payload but then ended up having different sha value for simple texts as  well.

Any help will be greatly appreciated .

```
byte[] payloadBytes = request.inputStream.bytes

String hashReceived = xHubSignature.substring(5)

String hashComputed = HmacUtils.hmacSha1Hex(facebookAppSecret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), payloadBytes)

log.info('Received {} computed {}', hashReceived, hashComputed)
```

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in the way I was accessing the data, something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express()
// Other imports 
app.listen(app.get('port'), ()=> 
{console.log('running on port', app.get('port'))});
```

The request body was accessed like this:

```
  app.post('/webhook/',  (req, res)=> 
   {
    let body = req.body;
    //By this time the encoded characters were already decoded and hence the hashcheck was failing. 

    //processing the data 
   });
```

The solution was to use natice httpServer to create the server and access the data so that the hashcheck was done on the raw data.

Probably this can be done using Express as well but it was not working for me.

This is what I did.

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require("url");
const crypto = require('crypto');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')

    let body = '';
    req.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk
    });

    if (urlItems.pathname === '/facebook/' && req.method === 'POST') {
        req.on('end', () => {

            let hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', appSecret);
            hmac.update(body, 'utf-8');
            let computedSig = `sha1=${hmac.digest('hex')}`;

            if (req.headers['x-hub-signature'] === computedSig) {
                 console.log(`${computedSig} matched ${req.headers['x-hub-signature']}`);
            } else {
                console.log(`Found ${computedSig} instead of ${req.headers['x-hub-signature']}`);
            }
            res.end(JSON.stringify({ status: 'ok' }))
        })
    }
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

**EDIT 1** : Due change in infra , we switched to Node hence the node code.